# Is it true that $\limsup_{n} \sum_k a_{kn} \leq \sum_k \limsup_n a_{kn}$ where the sum over $k$ is infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is easily shown that $$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n + b_n) \leq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n + \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$$ by noting that for any $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n) \leq\sup_{n \ge N_1 \vee N_2} (a_n + b_n) \leq \sup_{n \ge N_1} a_n + \sup_{n \ge N_2} b_n$$
and taking the infima over $N_1, N_2$ sequentially on the RHS yields the result.  Now suppose instead of two sequences, we have countably infinitely many, denoted by $\{a_{kn}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ($k$ refers to the sequence, $n$ for the element in the sequence).  Is it true that
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{kn} \qquad ?$$
If not, is it true when the sequences are constrained to be non-negative?  The same strategy does not work, since we would be taking $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ instead of simply finitely many $N_k$.

Comment: $a_{kn}=\frac 1 {kn}$ makes RHS $0$ and LHS $\infty$.

Comment: It the sequence of sequences $\mathbf{a}_n:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defines as $\mathbf{a}_n(k)=a_{kn}$ is bounded by a sequence $\mathbf{a}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_k|\mathbf{a}(k)|<\infty, then $$\limsup_n\sum^\infty_{k=1}\mathbf{a}_n(k)\leq\sum^\infty_{k=1}\limsup_n\mathbf{a}_k(n)$$